# Kickstart for CentOS9

Tags: linux, centos, pxe-boot, kickstart, centos9

Is there a kickstart feature in CentOS9?

When I try to install system-config-kickstart I am getting the following message

No match for argument: system-config-kickstart
Error: Unable to find a match: system-config-kickstart

Thanks everyone for your help
Imran

Comment: You don't need `system-config-kickstart` in order to use Kickstart. That package just provided a GUI editor for Kickstart files. You can continue to create Kickstart files using a text editor and use them to drive your automatic installs.

Comment: I’ve found that the documentation for CentOS Stream tends to be sorely lacking. In general, it seems like they expect you to defer to the Fedora or RHEL documentation. Take a look at the “Performing an advanced RHEL 9 installation” guide. Specifically, [Chapter 4. Creating Kickstart files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_9_installation/creating-kickstart-files_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user) probably has what you’re looking for.